# Is there a way to get "hg extdiff" to include subrepositories?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos, mercurial-extension

I would like to configure Mercurial to be able to do something like "hg diff -S", but with an external diff tool (kdiff3, specifically). The logical way to do this would be something like

```
hg extdiff -S -p kdiff3
```

However, this does not work because the extdiff extension does not support the "-S" option that many other mercurial commands use to include subrepositories. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not -- adding a `--subrepos` flag to the extdiff extension was not on the wishlish when my client sponsored the work on the other commands.